# iOS: PrepareForSegue not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem trying to pass data on to some other view controllers. I can successfully perform the segue, but the supplementary data I need doesn't make it through the segue.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    /// Identify the row number
    let rowNumber = indexPath.row
    let section = indexPath.section


    // Obtain the array of model names for the selected auto maker
    let moviesForSelectedGenre: AnyObject? = dict_Genre_dict2[genres[section]]
    dict2_Movie_MovieInfo = moviesForSelectedGenre as! Dictionary
    let movieNumber:String = "\(rowNumber+1)"
    movie = dict2_Movie_MovieInfo[movieNumber] as! [String]
    youtubeID = movie[2]
    movieTitle = movie[0]

    performSegueWithIdentifier("showTrailer1", sender: self)
}

func add(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("addMovie", sender: self)
}

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue == "showTrailer1"{

        // Obtain the object reference of the destination view controller
        let trailerViewController: MovieTrailerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MovieTrailerViewController

        //Pass the data object to the destination view controller object
        trailerViewController.youTubeMovieTrailerID = youtubeID
        trailerViewController.movieTitle = movieTitle
    }
    else if segue == "addMovie"{
        let addMovieViewController: AddMovieViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddMovieViewController
        addMovieViewController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

If anyone can identify why this is happening, that would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: prepare for segue is calling? have you tested using breakpoint?

Comment: Add `self.` before method. Like `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showTrailer1", sender: self)`

Comment: Can you show us the code for the trailerViewController?

Comment: Compare identifier Like `segue.identifier == "showTrailer1"`

Comment: that'll do it. Serves me right for trying to work on this at 2:30 am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not comparing with

```
segue.identifier
```

in

```
if segue == "showTrailer1"{
```

and

```
else if segue == "addMovie"{
```

Adding `.identifier` after `segue` will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `prepareForSegue` you have to use `segue.identifier` to check which segue has been called

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue.identifier == "showTrailer1"{

        // Obtain the object reference of the destination view controller
        let trailerViewController: MovieTrailerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MovieTrailerViewController

        //Pass the data object to the destination view controller object
        trailerViewController.youTubeMovieTrailerID = youtubeID
        trailerViewController.movieTitle = movieTitle
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "addMovie"{
        let addMovieViewController: AddMovieViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddMovieViewController
        addMovieViewController.delegate = self
    }
}
```